# -webkit-transform in -webkit-transition not working in css3

Tags: css

I am having trouble working with

```
-webkit-transform in -webkit-transition
```

but when I am using some `width` or `height` instead of `-webkit-transform in -webkit-transition` it is working fine.

when working with `-webkit-transform in  -webkit-transition` it is not showing any result (I am using chrome browser)

thanks in advance

Comment: can you plz post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you are using a div, span, p, or what so ever...

Just make sure apply **display:block/inline-block** also can use **float** but you have to apply height and width for it...

May this help for you...